# Angular 2: Directive Subscribe To Observables of a service

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-directives, angular2-observables

How would one have a directive subscribe to a service so that when the service updates, then the directive updates. So for example, lets say I want the view to react from a permission directive, and instead of submitting the data from each component into the directive when something changes, the directive would wait until a new permission update is pushed to it to reflect the changes from the service instead of a input change. So the permission directives manage themselves without the need of each component have to manage the data being injected into it.

```
 <div *hasPermission="'admin_user_reset'"></div>
```

And some directive that is subscribed to a service.

Comment: You should be a little more clear about what you're trying to accomplish. This all sounds doable / reasonable but what you're after is hard to figure out right now. I've designed / implemented several structural permission directives that sound like the one you're describing but I'm not sure if that's what you're getting at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RxJs `Subject`](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject) in your `Service` and `subscribe` to it into your `Directive`.

Each time the data changes, the `Subject` will **emit** the new data to your `Directive` that subscribes this `Subject`.

For example, in your **Service**:

```
...
private subject = new Subject<any>();

changePermission(permission: string) {
    this.subject.next({ text: permission });
}

getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
}
...
```

In your **Directive**:

```
...
permission: any;
subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    // subscribe to permission changes
    this.subscription = this.myService.getMessage().subscribe(permission => { this.permission = permission; });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ngOnChanges with SimpleChanges parameter, that compare new and previous value of input values after changes

```
@Input() public hasPermission: any; 

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
  if(changes.hasPermission){
    // add your control here
  }
}`
```

Comment: trying to not look for input changes, but take the input value to crosscheck against the user's subscribed permissions, and update when the permissions changes of the user and not the directive input